# get name of listbox item on click in wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying a while to get the displayed Value form a listBoxItem onClick.

I've built for testing a button which is doing what I need from the List:

```
    private void getDomains_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string selected = allDomains_ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Item is available " + selected);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item is not available");

        }
    }
```

But I need this behavior if I click on a ListItem like:

```
        private void allDomains_ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        try
        {
            string selected = allDomains_ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Item is available " + selected);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item is not available");

        }
    }
```

The listItems are generated with:

```
        public void enum_AllDomains()
    {
        Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        DomainCollection domains = currentForest.Domains;
        foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
        {
            allDomains_ListBox.Items.Add("somedomain.com");
            allDomains_ListBox.Items.Add("google.com");
        }

    }
```

That's my xaml for the listBox:

```
<ListBox Width="200" x:Name="allDomains_ListBox" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListBoxItem` container:

```
<ListBox Width="200" x:Name="allDomains_ListBox" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string clicked = ((ListBoxItem)sender).DataContext.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution, simple but hard for a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert sender object as the ListBoxItem and can access all properties like Name.

```
private void getDomains_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListBoxItem lstBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("Item is available " + lstBoxItem.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item is not available");

        }
    }
```